# How to update Wordpress custom SQL Select query for custom taxonomies so that syntax is correct?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates, tax-query, sql

I have a Wordpress website that written by third party web developer for version 2.9 before custom taxonomies were fully implemented.  We have since upgraded to latest wordpress version 3.5.x.  There is a SQL Select query that is generating a bunch of errors in the Wordpress error.log file.

In this template, we have a few custom taxonomies in use.  The one I am concerned about is listed below:

(wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy) jobs

A key point here is that **not all Wordpress posts are using the taxonomy field `jobs`**.  Therefore some post will not have any 'jobs' terms associated with it.

Here is the error I see repeated most often

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at 
line 9 for query 

  SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM wp_posts p, wp_terms t, wp_term_taxonomy tt,
  wp_term_relationships tr, wp_terms t2, wp_term_taxonomy tt2, wp_term_relationships tr2
    WHERE p.id = tr.object_id
      AND t.term_id = tt.term_id
      AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
      AND p.id = tr2.object_id
      AND t2.term_id = tt2.term_id
      AND tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id
      AND (tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND tt.term_id = t.term_id AND t.term_id = '22')
      AND (tt2.taxonomy = 'jobs' AND tt2.term_id = t2.term_id AND t2.name IN ())

made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
include('/themes/generic/page.php')
```

Here is the code snippet from the PHP template file.

```
<?
else :
$playlist = 0; $jobs = null; $job = null; $terms = null;
$jobs = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'jobs', array('fields'=>'names'));
$term_count = 0;
foreach($jobs as $job) :
    if ($term_count > 0) :
        $terms .= ", '".$job."'";
    else :  
        $terms .= "'".$job."'" ;
    endif;
    $term_count++;
endforeach;
$sql =  "
        SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts p, $wpdb->terms t, $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt, $wpdb->term_relationships tr, $wpdb->terms t2, $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt2, $wpdb->term_relationships tr2
        WHERE p.id = tr.object_id
        AND t.term_id = tt.term_id
        AND tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
        AND p.id = tr2.object_id
        AND t2.term_id = tt2.term_id
        AND tr2.term_taxonomy_id = tt2.term_taxonomy_id
        AND (tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND tt.term_id = t.term_id AND t.term_id = '22')
        AND (tt2.taxonomy = 'jobs' AND tt2.term_id = t2.term_id AND t2.name IN ($terms))
        ";
if (! $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql)) :
?>
```

From what I can deduce from the logic in the PHP file, I see the variable `$terms` is created with a `NULL` value.  A `foreach` loop is used to find any `jobs` terms and append them to the variable `$terms`. Next, the SQL Select query uses this variable in the last AND condition.

If there are values in the `$terms` variable, then the SQL evaulates w/o any problems.

But what happens if there are no values in the `$terms` variable?  It is `NULL`.  then the SQL generates a syntax error.

How can this be rewritten to handle `NULL` values for the `$terms` variable when the SQL query is run?

I hope I was complete enough in asking this question.  Thanks ahead of time for any input.

Comment: What prevents this being done using `WP_Query`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a direct SQL query, instead try the `WP_Query` tax queries e.g.:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => array( 22 )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'job',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => $terms,
            'operator' => 'IN'
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Where $terms is an array of term names.

Comment: I see how the WP_Query tax_queries are the replacement for direct SQL queries.  I am not as knowledgeable on SQL syntax and formatting so what happens if the variable $terms is an empty array, i.e. a post does not have any 'job' terms associated with this?  Does that break the query or will it gracefully ignore the empty array?

Comment: If I understand you, in my PHP file, I would copy your code to add variable `$args` & change the variable `$sql=` to `new WP_Query( $args );` 
Correct?

Comment: Then you have this: "SERVANT!! Find me all the things in the house starting with the letter '' ", "But master which letter did you refe..", "I SAID DO IT!!". Since everything in the house had a name that began with a letter, either no items were found, or the servant threw an SQL syntax error

Comment: Also, no, WP_Query is an object, a WP_Query object, it should be treated as such. I suggest you read up on Post loops and the main loop, specifically the "You don't know Query" presentation by Andrew Nacin. If you attempt to use it as an array of returned rows, you'll have issues as it is not an array.

Comment: Consequently, you can test if(empty($terms) and assign different parameters to an array and have `'tax_query' => $taxparameters`

Comment: Thanks for the updates.  I will take a look at the presentation (http://wordpress.tv/2012/06/15/andrew-nacin-wp_query/) and slideshare presentation (http://www.slideshare.net/andrewnacin/you-dont-know-query-wordcamp-netherlands-2012)

Answer (score 0):

What is meant to happen if $terms is empty? No records are selected?

If that's the case, you can probably get away with just setting the initial value of $terms to a dummy string:

```
$terms = 'no terms';
```

Comment: I believe that if $Terms is empty, then that would work.  Let me try it.

Comment: I tested this and I still got the SQL syntax errors.  thanks anyways. :-(

Comment: The WP_Query route is the best one to take, for sure, but if you just need a quick'n'dirty fix to get things back on the road, then you could try initializing $terms with a dummy string, ie `$terms = 'no terms'`. That should at least bypass that SQL error.